# Check if audio file exists on server

Tags: android, file, audio

How can I check if audio file exists on the server?

I want to check if file exists on the server and play it, otherwise want to exit from the onclick event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will do:

```
URL url = new URL("http://youraudiourl");
HttpURLConnection huc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
int responseCode = huc.getResponseCode();
if( responseCode == 200){
    // your audio file exists
}
```